# wildfly 23 server failing to start (WFLYCTL0013 error)

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, activemq-artemis

I am having a hard time undertanding how to solve this one. I keep getting errors on start up specifically on a containrized env - on regular env seems to work (which makes it stranger).
your help is very much appreciated.
from the logs:

```
2021-11-02 08:55:20,783 INFO  [org.jboss.as] WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 23.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 15.0.0.Final) started in 54029ms - Started 7123 of 7329 services (563 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
2021-11-02 08:55:20,810 INFO  [org.jboss.as] WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990/management
2021-11-02 08:55:20,832 INFO  [org.jboss.as] WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990
2021-11-03 01:00:03,891 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("read-attribute") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "messaging-activemq"),
    ("server" => "default"),
    ("runtime-queue" => "b119be15-b3ad-4d07-bafc-224c1745020b")
]) - failure description: "WFLYCTL0216: Management resource '[
    (\"subsystem\" => \"messaging-activemq\"),
    (\"server\" => \"default\"),
    (\"runtime-queue\" => \"b119be15-b3ad-4d07-bafc-224c1745020b\")
]' not found"
```

Comment: Someone is trying to read an attribute on the runtime queue  "b119be15-b3ad-4d07-bafc-224c1745020b". I don't know who or why. Also this queue seems to be generated so it feels strange to me.

Comment: Thanks Justin, diving into this we found that the metrics url which retrieves the vendor and base causes this. Is there a know issue here? I. Reffering to microprofile metrics we use for Prometheus scrapping

Comment: This is currently being tracked by https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-14509